# Woocommerce Store API - cant make POST request with headers

Tags: javascript, vue.js, rest, woocommerce, cors

I have hosted WordPress web site on Hostinger.com.
I am using the Woocommerce plugin and it's Store API (../wp-jsoin/wc/store)
I am using that Store API in my own frontend that runs on VueJS.

I have already set up allow origin header in httaccess, and I am able to make all kind of requests to Store API, but when I want to add headers to ma POST request I get CORS error in preflight request, so therefore I am not able to add Nonce to the POST requests that require it (checkout, cart etc.).

For example here is the error I get when I try to add item to cart:

[image]

Here is the code I am using for it (I am working in VueJS and using Axios for API requests):

```
axios.post('https://example.com/wp-json/wc/store/cart/add-item', {
  id: /* id of product */,
  quantity: /* some quantity */
},
{
  headers: {
    Nonce: /* Nonce i got previously */
  }
}).then(res => {
  console.log(res)
}).catch(err => {
  console.log(err)
})
```

In Postman and other clients everything works fine, but when I use axios it does not.
I dont know much about CORS or anything like that and I don't know what to do, I even tried to modify other CORS headers in .htaccess but nothing works.

I have been stuck on it for 3 days straight and I need to get it done.

Please help me or give me some hints.

Comment: Hey, I'm currently building [blockedbycors.dev](https://blockedbycors.dev/), a toolbox providing free tools to deal with these kinds of issues. You may want to give the CORS debugger a try.
My first guess would be that you need to allow some additional headers or allow that credentials are sent as part of your request.